# Como ignorar as outras ocorrências iguais ao capturar um trecho de uma string?

Tags: c#, string, substring

> Estou precisando pegar apenas o ID desta linha:
> "21 Julio André 21 Anos"
> Como o ID está no começo da linha e é igual a idade, as funções que eu tentei para dividir as strings foram Substring() e Split().

Segue o trecho do código abaixo:

```
    String linha = "21 Julio André 21 Anos";    

    String id = linha.Substring(0, linha.IndexOf(' '));//Captura o valor do ID no começo da linha
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    
    String resto = linha.Replace(id, "");
    Console.WriteLine(resto);
```

O que retorna no Console:

> 21
>
> Julio André  Anos

Mas seria ótimo se retornasse:

> 21
>
> Julio André 21 Anos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uma [expressão regular](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netcore-3.1) para substituir a devida porção de texto.

O classe `Regex` possui uma sobrecarga do método [`Replace(String, String, Int32)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_) que o permite definir o limite de substruções a serem efetuadas:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    String linha = "21 Julio André 21 Anos";    

    String id = linha.Substring(0, linha.IndexOf(' '));
    Console.WriteLine(id);

    //Instancia uma expressão regular que captura um ou mais números e um espaço
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d+\s");

    //Substitui apenas uma ocorrência
    String resto = reg.Replace(linha,"",1);
    Console.WriteLine(resto);
  }
}
```

Resultando em:

```
21
Julio André 21 Anos
```

Teste no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/KhakiFavorableDoom#main.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Se tem certeza que o `Id` é sempre o inicio da string e depois do `Id` sempre tem espaço, consegue fazer com o método `Split()` dessa forma.

```
using System;

namespace Main
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            string linha = "21 Julio André 21 Anos";    
            var arrayLinha = linha.Split(" ");

            Console.WriteLine(arrayLinha[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arrayLinha, 1, arrayLinha.Length - 1));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
// 21
// Julio André 21 Anos
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei seu próprio código, modificando somente o final.

```
string linha = "21 Julio André 21 Anos";

// criei uma variável para determinar a separação entre ID e informação
int sp = linha.IndexOf(' ');

// utilizei a variável sp para pegar o ID
string id = linha.Substring(0, sp);
Console.WriteLine(id);

// somei 1 à variável sp para setar o início da substring
// e então subtrai sp do total da string
// pegando assim somente o texto depois da separação ID/informação
string resto = linha.Substring(++sp, linha.Length - sp);
Console.WriteLine(resto);
```

A saída independe da quantidade de caracteres para o ID.